# How to change the sink priority in PulseAudio?

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, gnome3, pulse-audio

I have multiple output sound devices at home and at work. Especially, I want to automatically play sound via external soundcard when it is connected. So, I need some kind of the sink priorities.

Looking in the output of `pacmd list-sinks` gives me an idea that such priority is already there:

> ```
> index: 1
>     ...
>     priority: 9049
>     ...
> ```

But I can't find any way to change this priority from command-line. By the way in KDE I can rearrange the sinks using GUI, but I don't know if the order is related to sink's priority.

How to permanently change the sink priority via command-line or via GUI in GNOME 3.x?

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/885

Answer (score 1):

to prefer usb sound card I use `load-module module-switch-on-connect`.
Learned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113704/make-pulseaudio-prefer-external-audio-device